# Differences between "would" and "used to" when we are talking about habit

Tags: past-habitual

What is the differences between use "would" vs "used to"

I used to play football when I was a child.

I would play football when I was a child.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using “used to” when expressing something done in the past](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/using-used-to-when-expressing-something-done-in-the-past)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Would* is usually restricted to actions performed on specific occasions or under specific circumstances; it virtually always requires a modifier identifying these.

> *Whenever I had trouble with schoolwork* I would ask my friend Henry for help.
>   *If I wanted to be by myself* I would go to the park.
>   My parents used to read to me *at bedtime*.

*Used to* is employed for these, too, but it is also employed for actions performed without any sort of circumstantial specification, only a timespan locative:

> <sup>OK</sup>I used to play football.
>   <sup>OK</sup>I used to play football when I was a kid.

*Would* is not usually employed for these:

> <sup>∗</sup> I would play football.
>   <sup>?</sup> I would play football when I was a kid.

However, this restriction may not apply if the circumstantial specification can be inferred from the discourse context.

> **A:** What did you do if you needed help?
>   **B:** Oh, <sup>OK</sup>I would ask my friend Henry.

Comment: +1 - I'm not that fond of, *"I would play football when I was a child,"* but I have no problem with, *"When I was a child, I would play football whenever the weather was nice."*

Answer (score 1):

"Used to" expresses something done or habituated.  (See definition in  [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/used?q=used+to&searchDictCode=english#used__2)).

"Would" expresses a desire or intent, and is the past tense of "will".   (See definition in  [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would)).

"I used to play football when I was a child." can be re-expressed as "When I was a child, I played football"

"I would play football when I was a child" can be re-expressed as "When I was a child I had a desire to play football."

Obviously, if I played football as a child because of a desire, both forms of re-expression can be true.

By a literal interpretation, however, saying "I used to play football" can mean having played without any wish or desire to.   In comparison, saying "I would play football" expresses a desire, with no claim of having actually played.

Obviously other qualifications affect the interpretation.   But, without adornment ....

(Edited to add links following request).

Comment: I agree with your rephrasings. I also think that first meaning is what the O.P. probably wants to express. The use of _would_ to mean _wanted to_ sounds a bit archaic and I would not recommend using it that way in day-to-day speech.