# What did you use to cook or What did you used to cook, which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, used-to

I have confusion with some grammatical facts. So I am looking for help here.

Which one should be correct?

A. What did you use to cook?

B. What did you used to cook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using “used to” vs "would" when expressing something done in the past.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/using-used-to-vs-would-when-expressing-something-done-in-the-past) Note the comment under that question: *this is one of the seven verbs [in which Pullum, a linguist] analyzes **-to** not as a separate word (as in the so-called **phrasal verbs**) but as a suffix (forming **wanna, gonna, usta, hafta, gotta, oughta, sposta**)*.

Comment: ...and I'm pretty sure our own resident linguist John Lawler has pointed out in the past that actually, even native speakers can't agree on whether the "past tense" version should be written *I didn't **use** to do that* or *I didn't **used** to do it* (there being no real possibility of this reflecting any difference in pronunciation).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica No, I think I have explained.

Comment: naasif - don't worry too much about the ***orthography*** (per above comment, there's no consensus on how the past tense "habitual" sense should be written). What matters is how it's ***pronounced***. With a soft "Z" sound, it means *What implements / raw materials did you use when cooking?*, but with a hard "S", it means *What meals did you usually prepare?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Look in general we use "used to" for for what we used to do in past, right? But when you ask some one about that like, "Did you used/use to..?" I think when I use "use to" it's not the same thing as "used to". "Used to " has it's own special meaning. THat's made the confusion. I hope you have got it now.

Comment: naasif - I'm a native speaker with a degree that includes linguistics, so I know this stuff inside out. More importantly - have ***you*** got it? :)

Comment: Please don't use: `wanna`, `gonna`, `usta`, `hafta`, `gotta`, `oughta`, `sposta`.  Some of those are very informal slang, and many of them are completely made up for the sake of that comment / not words.

Comment: @naasif - Your statement about the phrase pronunciation may be true in the dialects you are used to, but is not true generally.   For example, a speaker of the "Queen's English" would certainly find your statement incorrect.

Comment: @BadZen: I cut & pasted that list *(wanna, gonna, usta, hafta, gotta, oughta, sposta)* from snailcar♦'s comment under the linked question - which was citing [UK linguist GK Pullum's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_K._Pullum) list of what he calls "therapy verbs" in *The Morpholexical Nature of English to-Contraction* (1997). I certainly didn't "make them up" for the purposes of my comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you for your help!

Comment: naasif - To satisfy my curiosity, when you actually posted this question, had you ever ***heard*** (or read about) utterances such as *She used to like him* (and more specifically, did you know that ***used*** there is pronounced different to *She used drugs when she was a student*)?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica No, I didn't.

Comment: Good. That's by far the most important thing to learn from your examples. The business about how to *write* the "Past Tense" version in my first example below is "interesting" for some people - but since it's not something even most native speakers would easily understand in detail, it's not very important from your point of view as a learner. But I'm glad you got what you asked for / needed here.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I voted to close because this has been asked and answered more that once before, but I can't resist flagging up [this somewhat striking example...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22two%20things%20you%20didn%27t%20use%20to%20do%22)

[image]

That's actually from a book intended to teach English to non-native speakers! The writer seems blissfully unaware that he's written the past tense both different ways ***in the same sentence***. I think that's proof enough of my comment that ***there is no "correct" orthography***. (But I'd expect any halfway competent *teacher* to be at least *consistent!* :)

Note that there's no possibility of ambiguity (doubt as to whether *What did you use(d) to cook?* means *A: What implements did you use to cook?*, or *B: What did you usually cook?*), because they're *enunciated* completely differently. The first meaning always has a soft "Z", whereas the second always has a hard "S" sound, and blends seamlessly into the infinitive marker that follows (as ***usta***).

---

EDIT: (2 days after original post)
I must accept at least one of the points made in the extended discussion my answer led to (now [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102268/discussion-on-answer-by-fumblefingers-reinstate-monica-what-did-you-use-to-cook)). If we rephrase slightly and switch to a different verb...

> 1: *Explain what you **wanted** to do.*
>    2: *Explain what you **didn't want** to do.*

...it should be clear that the second version *doesn't* inflect ***want*** for Past Tense. That's because we've already done this with the auxiliary verb ***did*** (so ***have*** is just an "unmarked infinitive", that doesn't include the "infinitive marker" ***to*** [have] in such contexts).

But my substantive point is that few native speakers would consciously recognise that point for OP's exact example, and most (if not all) of us can neither pronounce nor *hear* the difference between ***use*** and ***used*** in such contexts, so it doesn't really make much difference how it's *written*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102268/discussion-on-answer-by-fumblefingers-reinstate-monica-what-did-you-use-to-cook).

Comment: I would edit out the "striking example". I don't know why you are keeping it.

Comment: I would rather see both my reply here *and* your comment moved to chat. This extended discussion serves little purpose for learners, since it's mostly about something that only really interests knowledgeable pedants.

Answer (score -1):

In my speech, I never use "use(d) to" in the primary clauses of questions in this way.

However, many English speakers do (it is dialectual).   It's always "used to" with the first person ("I"/"we").  "Use" is more common than "used" with second ("you") person, but I've heard both ("used" is common in the Southern US and in AAVE).    Some websites will say it is incorrect that way, but it is definitely in use.

However, there is another problem with the diction here.

> What did you use to cook?

^ This sounds like you might be using the phrase 'use to' in a different way - asking what tools or items were used to help you cook!   "What did you use to cook?  Did you use the spatula?  Did you use the knife?"   So I would find another way to disambiguate or convey your actual meaning, perhaps:

> What dishes did you use to cook?

or avoid "use(d) to" altogether.

If you say it in the southern english / AAVE way ("you... used to") - your B) above - it's not ambiguous, and fine as is.

Comment: In Early Modern English _use to_ could be used in the present tense for _be in the habit of_ - see https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-used-to-or-use-to

Comment: I think the sense of ***use(d) to = was accustomed to*** has been ***mainstream*** for centuries. If you *never* use it, I'd say that suggests it's *your* speech that's somehow "dialectal, non-mainstream".

Comment: I didn't say I ever don't use it, I said I don't use it in the primary clauses of questions.   And **all speech is dialect**.   The notion that there is some orthographic English and "dialects" which are variations or perversions of that One True English is prescriptivism and should be eliminated.   Check your equation of "dialectal" and "non-mainstream", please.   (And maybe read more carefully before putting people on blast for no reason.)

Comment: And to put a fine point on it:  please definitely do so especially when quoting / attributing.